# How can I stop the enemy from instantly killing the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the player health script to decrease health value once the enemy shoots the player game object with the enemy projectile script How can I get this health script to work? I attached the script to the player but the player game object dies instantly when shot. I added a collision method to get component projectiles am I on the right path? any feedback is welcomed.

```
     using UnityEngine;
     using UnityEngine.UI;
     using System.Collections;

     public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
     {
     [SerializeField] GameObject deathFX;
     [SerializeField] Transform parent;
     public Image Bar;
     public Text Text;
     public float max_health = 100f;
     public float cur_health = 0f;


     //Use this for initialization
     void Start()
      {
     // Initialize the health that is given
     cur_health = max_health;

    InvokeRepeating("decreaseHealth", 0f, 2f);

    }
    void Update()
    {
    if (cur_health <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);   //if the player has no health point left, destroy the player.
    }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
    if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Projectiles>())
    {
    max_health -= cur_health;
        //if the collision object has a homing script, minus player health by damageToPlayer
    }
    }
    void decreaseHealth()
    {
    //Subtract the health at the following rate
    //Check if the health is 0 before we do any damage
    if (cur_health < 0)
    {
        cur_health = 0;
    }

    //make a new variable and divide the current health my the maximum health
    //this is because the fill value goes from 0 to 1
    float calc_health = cur_health / max_health; // 70 / 100 = 0.7
    SetHealth(calc_health);

    //Change the color of the health bar
    if (cur_health != 0 && cur_health <= max_health / 1.6 && cur_health > max_health / 2.9) // on the scale of 1000, if health <= 625 and is greater than 345, do the following
    {
        Bar.color = new Color32(171, 162, 53, 255);
    }
    else if (cur_health != 0 && cur_health <= max_health / 2.9) // on the scale of 1000, if health <= 625, do the following
    {
        Bar.color = new Color32(158, 25, 25, 255);
    }
}

void SetHealth(float myHealth)
{
    //defill the bar based on the current health
    Bar.fillAmount = myHealth;

    //change the text to display the amount of health
    Text.text = cur_health.ToString("f0") + "/100";
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us where you are calling `ApplyDamage`? Also, when you say the player dies when shot, do you mean the player gameobject gets destroyed?

Comment: `GameObject fx = Instantiate(deathFX,....` seems suspect maybe post that code

Comment: This is all the code I have put together so far and yes I mean the player game object gets destroyed. I would like to know what I missing in his code any guidance/hints to what I missed will be appreciated. I understand if it does not makes sense to anyone. I'm trying though :/

Comment: how much is `damageToTake`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am completely misunderstanding the question, but I think all you need is an if statement.

```
public void ApplyDamage(int damageToTake)
{
    Debug.Log(Time.frameCount + ": ApplyDamage was called.");
    currentHealthPlayer -= damageToTake;
    if (currentHealthPlayer <= 0)  //Only apply death effect if health goes to zero
    {
        Debug.Log("Player met an unfortunate end. Time of death: " + Time.frameCount);
        GameObject fx = Instantiate(deathFX, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        fx.transform.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recently updated my post please look over my script again if you have the time.